# How is the announcer badge awarded?

Tags: support, badges

How is it determined that a member be awarded the announcer badge?  I've linked a couple questions that may have had the required number of IP addresses visit.  How would the site know that I am the one that posted these links if in fact the required number of IP's have visited SE from my links?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Announcer Badge description](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/announcer) says:

> Share a link to a question later visited by 25 unique IP addresses.
>   This badge can be awarded multiple times.

The detection works pretty simply. Right now, if I click on the **share** button under your question, I'll get the following link:

```
https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2790/15133
```

This link is different for every user. The first number, `2790`, is the question ID. You can see the link works perfectly without the last number. This second number, `15133` in my case, is my user ID here on Chemistry SE. This means that when someone follows this link a point will be added to my Announcer Badge of this question. The [Booster](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/badges/60/booster) and [Publicist](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/badges/61/publicist) badges work the same way, with higher requirements.

Hence, the link you (Brinn Belyea) get from the **share** button should be

```
https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2790/5601
```

It's important to note a few things about these badges:

- You **must** use the link from the **share** button, otherwise the link can't be traced back to you. Copying from the browser address bar **won't work**.
- Only links followed from the outside of the Stack Exchange network will count. Linking from Chemistry SE, Physics SE (or any other SE) won't count.

Sources:

[Why don't I get the Announcer badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156090/why-dont-i-get-the-announcer-badge)

[How does the announcer badge work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78160/how-does-the-announcer-badge-work)

[For what purposes is my user id used when sharing a link?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113638/for-what-purposes-is-my-user-id-used-when-sharing-a-link)